# OnCollisionEnter with multiple colliders Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have an issue with detecting collisions in Unity. I am developing a VR application with hand tracking, using Unity3D v.2022.3.14f1 and the XR Interaction Toolkit v.2.5.2. I need to detect collisions between the hand and an object (i.e., a 3D cube). I setup the right hand with capsule colliders on the fingers, and a box collider on the palm. The setup is as follows:

[image: hand colliders]

The hierarchy of the hand is such that each collider is on a custom GameObject as a child of the corresponding finger. Here there is a screenshot with the hierarchy of the first fingers:

[image: hand hierarchy]

I have the following script to detect collisions between a `CollidinObject` object and the hand, to send haptics feedback through an Arduino board using the `Uduino` library:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Uduino;

public class CollidingObject : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private int pinToActivate;
        private bool _isColliding;
    
        private void Start()
        {
            _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            _isColliding = false;
        }

        private void Update(){
           if(_isColliding){
                UduinoManager.Instance.digitalWrite(pin, State.HIGH);
           }
           else{
                UduinoManager.Instance.digitalWrite(pin, State.LOW);
           }
       }

        private void OnCollisionStay(Collision other)
        {
            if(!other.gameObject.CompareTag("HandCollider")) return;
            
            Debug.Log("Colliding with hand.");
            _isColliding = true;
        }
        private void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
        {
           if(!other.gameObject.CompareTag("HandCollider")) return;

           Debug.Log("Collision with hand ended, stopping haptic feedback!");
           _isColliding = false;
        }
    }
```

However, I am facing some issues, as it does not send the haptic feedbacks properly. I tested my scripts with other objects, with just one collider on both of them, and it works, so I suppose the problem is the multiple colliders structure of the hand. However, when inserting some way to trigger the `OnCollisionExit` script only when all the colliders end the collision, it does not work.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: have you tried putting a kinematic Rigidbody on the root of the hand? Usually afaik in that case all child colliders are basically treated a one and events properly triggered on that root object => might be easier then to track the collision the other way round, not on your object waiting for a hand but on your hand waiting for an object

Comment: also - and this is just a sidenote: instead of setting and poll-checking a flag, why not rather directly call the according line right away?

Comment: I tried to "invert" the detection of the collision, namely adding a script on the hand to detect them (and also adding the Rigidbody at the root of the hand), but it still don't work properly. I have the same issues as before

Comment: so what exactly is the issue? `don't work properly` is unfortunately not a very precise description ;) Same for `when inserting some way to trigger the OnCollisionExit script only when all the colliders end the collision, it does not work.` .. it would be great to see the code for this